# Visual Studio Code / create Git Project with virtual environment

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I wonder when working with vitual environment, is it better to use git before running activate script ?

```
 .venv/scripts/activate
```

In early days, I used to send to my repo all the python libraries, thus I was adviced not to do it.
As I would like to start from scratch a new repo from my local computer to github, I wonder what would be the best method.

Comment: use a `.gitignore` file to prevent the virtual environment to be tracked, if it is a subdir of the workspace

Comment: When I have created my new repo in github, I have activated the .gitignore for visual studio code.